# Issue on TableMapping parameter while creating AWS DMS Migration Task

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am creating AWS DMS Migration task using python boto3. While specifying the TableMapping parameter I am getting error.
code:

```
response = dmsc.create_replication_task(
ReplicationTaskIdentifier='Abhisek-task12',
SourceEndpointArn='',
TargetEndpointArn='',
ReplicationInstanceArn='',
MigrationType='full-load',
TableMappings="file:////home/abhisek/shellscript/FinalScripts-copy/table- mapping-blog.json"
```

json file: table-mapping-blog.json

```
{
  "TableMappings": 
  [
   {
    "Type": "Include", 
    "SourceSchema": "cloudthat_blog", 
    "SourceTable": "%" 
    }
   ]
  }
```

error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the
>   CreateReplicationTask operation: Invalid Table Mappings document

Am i missing anything in the json file?

Comment: Your json is a valid table mapping json. Can you paste the code /command using which you create the task? Also try new table mapping json , it allows transformations too. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.html#CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this same issue. Finally got the info that [this is a documentation bug for dms](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1121). The documentation describes the TableMappings value would be a json file with 'file://mappings.json' prefix. But it actually accepts raw json string value. Here is a code sample I've successfully completed a mysql-mysql homogeneous migration.

create_task.py:

```
ReplicationTaskIdentifier='simple-task'
SourceEndpointArn=''
TargetEndpointArn=''
# MigrationType='full-load'|'cdc'|'full-load-and-cdc'
MigrationType='full-load'

TableMappings="""{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-name": "1",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "dms_mysql",
                "table-name": "%"
            },
            "rule-action": "include"
        }
    ]
}"""


response = client.create_replication_task(ReplicationTaskIdentifier=ReplicationTaskIdentifier,
                                          SourceEndpointArn=SourceEndpointArn,
                                          TargetEndpointArn=TargetEndpointArn,
                                          ReplicationInstanceArn=ReplicationInstanceArn,
                                          MigrationType=MigrationType,
                                          TableMappings=TableMappings
                                          )
```

Just to be clear, I don't know how you got that json format, I've taken my json string from manual task creation in AWS DMS ui. Even though they don't have that much of details of json formating, I mean what are the json keys AWS API accepts or not. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

the documentation does appear this way, and I ran into the same issue as you and @Hakuna-Matata did, however you can pass in a JSON file into the CLI, I had the same error and simply removed the array and the "TableMappings" tag

```
   {
    "Type": "Include", 
    "SourceSchema": "cloudthat_blog", 
    "SourceTable": "%" 
    }
```

I have not tried with the above, however this worked like a champ for me:

```
{ 
"rules": [ 
    { "rule-type": "selection", 
      "rule-id": "1", 
      "rule-name": "1", 
      "object-locator": 
                    { 
                        "schema-name": "SCHEMA-NAME", 
                        "table-name": "TABLE-NAME" 
                    }, 
      "rule-action": "include", 
      "filters": 
                [
                     { 
                        "filter-type": "source", 
                        "column-name": "DATE-COLUMN-TO-FILTER", 
                        "filter-conditions": 
                            [ 
                                { 
                                    "filter-operator": "gte", 
                                    "value": "2018-03-15 00:00:00" 
                                } 
                            ] 
                    } 
                ] 
    } 
   ] 
}
```

I did the same for --replication-task-settings

```
{  
   "TargetMetadata":{  
      "TargetSchema":"",
      "SupportLobs":false,
      "FullLobMode":false,
      "LobChunkSize":64,
      "LimitedSizeLobMode":true,
      "LobMaxSize":32,
      "LoadMaxFileSize":0,
      "ParallelLoadThreads":0,
      "ParallelLoadBufferSize":0,
      "BatchApplyEnabled":false,
      "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled":false
   },
   "FullLoadSettings":{  
      "TargetTablePrepMode":"DO_NOTHING",
...
```

and then running it all worked

```
aws dms create-replication-task  --replication-task-identifier dmsdynamodbtask-name --source-endpoint-arn my-source-endpoint-arn --target-endpoint-arn my-target-endpoint-arn --replication-instance-arn my-replication-instance-arn --migration-type full-load-and-cdc --table-mappings file://./TableMappings/my-table.json --replication-task-settings file://./ReplicationTaskSettings.json
```